# Why is `print(object)` displaying `<__main__. object at 0x02C08790>`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting

```
<__main__.Camera object at 0x02C08790>
```

and I don't know why.

I would like the code to go from Calc_Speed to Counter and then back to Calc_Speed basically in a loop.

```
class Camera():
    distance = 2
    speed_limit = 20
    number_of_cars = 0

    def Calc_Speed(self):
        registration = input("Registration Plate: ")
        Speeding_List=[]
        start = float(input("Start time: "))
        end = float(input("End Time: "))
        speed = self.distance/(end-start)
        print(("Average Speed: ") + str(round(speed, 2)) + (" mph"))
        if speed > self.speed_limit:
            list3= [str(self.registration)]
            Speeding_List.append(list3)
            print("Vehicles Caught Speeding: " + str(Speeding_List))
            return(program.Counter())
        else:
            print("Vehicle Not Speeding")
            return(program.Counter())

    def Counter():
        self.number_of_cars = self.number_of_cars + 1
        print("Number Of Cars Recorded: " + str(self.number_of_cars))                                 
        return(program.Calc_Speed())



program = Camera()
print(program)
```

Comment: you print a `Speed_Camera` object. What do you expect?

Comment: Your code has indentation errors, and there is nothing called `Speed_Camera` defined.  Also, you never said what you intend the program to do, so no one can tell you how to make it do what you want.

Comment: @BrenBarn . I changed the name of the class to Camera from Speed_Camera without changing the rest of the code. Oops! Sorry :)

Comment: the reason you get that string printed is because you are creating an instance of a class and prinitng it, but the class itself does not define what should be returned when you use `print` on it. also your functions within your class are not being called.

Comment: @JamesKent  so if I put something like " print (program.Calc_Speed()) i" it would work?

Comment: that would call the `Calc_Speed` function and then print what it returns.

Comment: Iterate through the object to look inside.

Answer (score 12):

When you just print an object, it shows the object id (like `<__main__.Camera object at 0x02C08790>`), which is totally indecipherable to us mortals. You can get around this by defining a `__str__` or `__repr__` function to display the data for the instance in a custom way.

In your case:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<__main__.Camera: distance = " + str(self.distance) + "; speed_limit = " + str(self.speed_limit) + "; number_of_cars = " + str(self.number_of_cars) + ">"
```

If there were an instance of `Camera` with the starting variable values, it would return

`"<__main__.Camera: distance = 2; speed_limit = 20; number_of_cars = 0>"`.

The `<__main__.Camera object at 0x02C08790>` is the how the system remembers it, but aside from showing what type of object it is, it's mostly useless.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than printing the object itself, you would want to print a function of that object. If you replaced the last line with:

```
print(program.Calc_Speed())
```

The program would work more similarly to what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*I wrote this answer for a linked closed duplicate.  Since it goes into more detail about *why* the output looks like this, and this is apparently the canonical question, I'm putting it here.*

Because you are printing an *object*, and that *object* doesn't have a `__repr__`  or `__str__` method explaining how to print it.

Implementing these methods will let you print a 'description' of your object.

## Background

When you call `print(thing)` in python, print looks to see if `thing` has a `__str__` method, and calls it if it does.  If it doesn't, it looks to see whether thing has a `__repr__` method, and calls *that* if it does.  If not, it keeps looking up the class hierarchy,* until it ends up with `object`, from which all user defined classes inherit (nowadays...).  That's the method you're seeing here.

We can try this out:

```py
>>> "I am a string".__str__()
"I am a string"
>>> "I am a string".__repr__()
"'I am a string'"
```

Yes! strings are objects in python.  In fact, *everything* is an object.

```py
>>> obj = object() # base class for all classes
obj.__str__()
'<object object at 0x7a87787987979877>'
```

So it's the fallback `.__str__`, which just prints that it's a `thing` at such and such a ram address.

*alright, it'll apply MRO, but I was keeping it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found with Dash:

```
print(InputData.marker_value)
>>> <dash._callback.NoUpdate object at 0x7f52b29fdfa0>
```

```
print(InputData().marker_value)
>>> "value expected"
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Sandford Basset
You can try as well

> program.Calc_Speed()