# calling class with user input

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods

I'm very new to `Python` and programming.  I was trying to create a little program that tells you the quarterback for NFL teams.  I got it to work but looking to see if there is a less repetitive way of doing this for two reasons:

- So that I don't have to type as much, and
- Because it would keep my code shorter.

I was trying to have the users input plug into the class calling so I wouldn't have to type in so many and use a lot of `elif` commands, ex:

```
x= input("")`
print (x.qb,x.num)
```

Here is what I have so far. It works for now but I would like an easier way to finish it:

```
class football:
    def __init__(self,qb,num):                                                                                         
        self.qb = qb
        self.num = num

Niners = football("Gabbert", "02" )
Bears = football("CUTLER, JAY","06") 
Bengals = football ("Dalton, Andy","14")
Bills =football (" Taylor, Tyrod", "05")
Broncos =football ("Sanchez, Mark", "06")
Browns =football ("MCCOWN, JOSH", "13")
Bucaneers =football ("Winston, Jameis", "03")
Cardinals =football ("PALMER, CARSON", "03")
Chargers =football ("RIVERS, PHILIP", "17")
Cheifs =football ("SMITH, ALEX", '11')
Colts =football ("Luck, Andrew",' 12' )
Cowboys =football ("Romo,Tony","09")
Dolphins =football ("Tannehill, Ryan", '17' )
Eagles =football ("Bradford, Sam", '07')
Falcons =football ("RYAN, MATT",' 02' )
Giants =football ("MANNING, ELI", '10' )
Jaguars =football ("Bortles, Blake", '05')
Jets =football ("Smith, Geno",' 07' )
Lions =football ("Stafford, Matthew", '09' )
Packers =football ("RODGERS, AARON", '12')
Panthers =football ("Newton, Cam",' 01' )
Patriots =football ("BRADY, TOM", '12')
Raiders =football ("Carr, Derek",' 04')
Rams =football ("Foles, Nick", '05')
Ravens =football ("FLACCO, JOE",' 05')
Redskins =football ("Cousins, Kirk", '08')
Saints =football ("BREES, DREW",' 09' )
Seahawks =football ("Wilson, Russell", '03')
Steelers =football ("ROETHLISBERGER, BEN",' 07')
Texans =football ("Osweiler, Brock", '17')
Titans =football ("Mariota, Marcus",' 08' ) 
Vikings=football ("Bridgewater, Teddy", '05' )

def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("===============================")
        func()
        print("===============================")
    return wrap

def print_text():
    print("Who\s your NFL Quarterback? ")

decorated = decor(print_text)
decorated()

team= input(" Enter your teams name here:").lower()

if team == "cowboys":
    print (Cowboys.qb,Cowboys.num) 
elif team == "niners":
    print (Niners.qb,Niners.num)
```

Comment: I think a dictionary would be a more appropriate data structure here.

Comment: OK I  will read up on those like I said very new to all this. in fact this is my first little program I've made.

Comment: I think this question would be more suitable on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good option would be to use a dictionary to reference each instance of `football`, which would avoid a massive `if`, `elif` structure at the end:

```
class football:
    def __init__(self,qb,num):
        self.qb = qb
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return self.qb + ", " + self.num
teams = {
"Niners" : football("Gabbert", "02" ),
"Bears" : football("CUTLER, JAY","06"),
"Bengals" : football ("Dalton, Andy","14"),
"Bills" : football (" Taylor, Tyrod", "05")} #etc
#I didn't include the whole dictionary for brevity's sake

def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("===============================")
        func()
        print("===============================")
    return wrap

def print_text():
    print("Who\s your NFL Quarterback? ")

decorated = decor(print_text)
decorated()

team = input("Enter your teams name here:").capitalize()
print(teams[team])
```

You will notice that the teams are now in a dictionary, so that the `football` instance for each team can be easily accessed by indexing the dictionary using the team name. This is what was done on the last line with the statement `print(teams[team])`.

`teams[team]` returns the value associated with the key that is stored inside `team`. If the user enters `Chiefs`, for example, the string `'Chiefs'` would be stored in `team`. Then when you try to index the dictionary using `teams[team]`, it would access the dictionary entry for `'Chiefs'`.

But notice that what is returned from `teams[team]` is a `football` object. Normally, when you just print an object, it prints something that looks a little like what was going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832999/main-object-at-0x02c08790-python/30836827#30836827), because it is simply printing some raw information about the object. The way to have it return that you want it to is to define a `__repr__` or `__str__` method in the class (more info about that [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#construction)). This is exactly what I have done in the `football` class, so that when an instance of the class in printed, it will print the desired information in the desired format.

---

Another approach is to do away with the class altogether, and simply have a dictionary whose values are tuples containing the quarterback's name and their number as elements. The code would look a little like this:

```
teams = {
"Niners" : ("Gabbert", "02" ),
"Bears" : ("CUTLER, JAY","06"),
"Bengals" : ("Dalton, Andy","14"),
"Bills" : (" Taylor, Tyrod", "05")} #etc
# Again, not including the whole dictionary for brevity's sake

def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("===============================")
        func()
        print("===============================")
    return wrap

def print_text():
    print("Who\s your NFL Quarterback? ")

decorated = decor(print_text)
decorated()

team = input("Enter your teams name here:").capitalize()
print(teams[team][0], teams[team][1])
```

This time `teams[team]` is a tuple. The last line is printing the first element (the quarterback's name), then the second element (the number).

---

The second one is cleaner and requires less code, but it really is a matter of personal preference.

There is more information about dictionaries in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Also, I shortened the code sample for the sake of brevity, but you can see the full code samples on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xYtJBT9n).

Comment: Oh wow thank you  so much Xamuel Schulman I really appreciate it and very informative I was starting to do the second one before reading this didn't realize I could leave them in (), though they had to be put in []  thanks again definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: yes I'm new to this site/app do I do that with the check to the left

Comment: @JesseHinojosa Yes. Thank you so much.