# value at 0x20c16d6c808, how to extract the result?

Tags: python, google-translate

How to extract the value from the format 0x20c16d6c808, can't find any other functions for that.

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

translator.translate('안녕하세요.', dest='en',src='auto')
Out[20]: <googletrans.models.Translated at 0x20c16d6c808>
```

It shows in-line like

[image]

Comment: `0x20c16d6c808` is just a memory address. All that message is telling you is that you have an object of type `googletrans.models.Translated`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<\_\_main\_\_. object at 0x02C08790>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832999/main-object-at-0x02c08790)

Comment: to get the value, there is no list function

Comment: It would be useful for you to [read through the documentation](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that was linked on the [`googletrans`](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) package page, and see that you need to [access the `.text` attribute of the result](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#googletrans.Translator).

Answer (score 2):

The in-line output is actually more helpful. It says that the Translated class has the properties `src`, `dest`, `text`, etc. You can get their values by simply typing

```
result = translator.translate('안녕하세요.', dest='en',src='auto')
print(result.text)
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/blob/master/googletrans/models.py)